# Based on condition, match and replace column values

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have the following `Series object` extracted from `dataframe` df1.

```
df1['K'][25:35]

25     26
26     27
.......
33    UT5
34    XYZ
Name: K, dtype: object
```

I want to convert 'K' values to 'U' if the string value starts with 'U'. Else, if it starts with '1' or '2' (string), I want to replace with 'S'. Else, I want to leave the value intact. Something like:

```
25      S
26      S
.......
33      U
34    XYZ
```

I tried if-else way, but not getting a result. I know for sure the code to assign values is not correct. Any suggestions?

```
if (df1['K'].str[0].isin(['1','2'])):
    df1['K'].str='S'
elif (df1['K'].str[0].isin(['U'])):)
    df1['K'].str='U'

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with `default` parameter with same column (returned values if no match), for second mask is possible use [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) because compared only one value:

```
s = df1['K'].str[0]
m1 = s.isin(['1','2'])
m2 = s.eq('U')
```

Another idea is use [`Series.str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) for masks:

```
m1 = df1['K'].str.startswith(('1','2'))
m2 = df1['K'].str.startswith('U')
```

---

```
df1['K'] = np.select([m1, m2], ['S','U'], default=df1['K'])
print (df1)
      K
25    S
26    S
33    U
34  XYZ
```